# In Vim, how to auto format current line when i typed semicolon in c++ files

Tags: c++, vim, code-formatting

For example: current line is

```
int i=0
```

After i typed semicolon,

```
int i = 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need an `inoremap` on `;` (and restricted to the current buffer -- `:h :map-<buffer>`). On the mapping, you'll have to parse the current line for (exactly?) one `=` sign. Reformat and be sure to move the cursor back.

The traps:

- should the mapping be redoable? In that case you'll have to move the cursor with `<c-g>U<left>` and `<right>` as many times as required. Otherwise, a plain use of `getline()` + `substitute()` + `setline()` would work (and be quite simple actually) -> `:call setline('.', substitute(getline('.'), '\s*[<>!=]\?=\s*', ' = ', 'g'))`.
- if UTF-8 characters could appear like in `auto head = "tête";, you won't be able to use`strlen()`.

Note, that clang-format is may be already able to do this kind of stuff -- but I cannot guarantee it permits to produce re-doable sequences.

```
" rtp/ftplugin/c/c_reformat_on_semincolon.vim
" The reodable version.
function! s:semicolon() abort
  " let suppose the ';' is at the end of the line... 
  " and that there aren't multiple instructions of the same line
  let res = ''
  let line = getline('.')
  let missing_before = match(line, '\V\S=')
  let c = col('.') - 1
  if missing_before >= 0
     " prefer lh-vim-lib lh#encoding#strlen(line[missing_before : c])
     let offset = c - missing_before " +/- 1 ?
     let res .= repeat("\<c-g>U\<right>", offset)
           \ . ' '
     if line =~ '\V=\S'
         let res .= "\<c-g>U\<left> "
         let offset -= 1 " or 2 ?
     endif
     " let offset +/-= 1 ??
  else
     let offset = c - missing_after" +/- 1 ?
     let res .= repeat("\<c-g>U\<right>", offset)
           \ .  ' '
  endif
  let res .=  repeat("\<c-g>U\<left> ", offset)
  return res
endfunction

inoremap <buffer> ; <c-r>=<sid>semicolon()<cr>
```

Note that this code is completely untested. You'll have to adjust offsets, and may be fix the logic.